# Linq :DataTable select does not work if column name has space in it?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net, datatable

I want to select rows from DataTable. Select criteria includes anding and the columns name have a space b/w them as you can see below:

```
int distributionLineIdex = import.VendorInvoiceLineDetailTable.Select    
       ("Number='AMEX0311_00011' and Line number='001'").Count();
```

I am getting the following exception :

```
Syntax error: Missing operand after 'number' operator.
```

[image]
What am I missing here  ?

Comment: Do integer fields need quotes in SQL?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use

```
[Line Number] = '001'
```

instead

Comment: What if the column name has any special characters , something like November 23, 2016 ??

Answer (score 3):

This is also true when the field name in DataTable is numeric. In that case use:

```
[2] = 7878 AND [6] = 'eee'
```